# Conversion of Date object to calendar object

Tags: java, java.util.calendar

I had a function called as setDueDate(Calendar arg0).But, the value in the field is Date of format "yyyy/MM/dd".Is there any way to convert Date object to Calendar and pass it to the function.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185966/converting-a-date-object-to-a-calendar-object

Comment: Firstly,Thanks for responding.The solution given there is returning Calendar object,that is fine.but when I pass that object to my function the Date is not in specified format right...?

Comment: Could you post some code, that would be helpfull

Comment: Method for converting date to desired format:                 
private static String convertDateToString(Date date)
 {
  SimpleDateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
  date=new Date();
  String strDate=dateFormat.format(date);
  return strDate;
 }

Comment: Method for getting Calendar Object:                            
private static Calendar getCalendarFromString(String str_date)
   throws ParseException {
  DateFormat formatter;
  Date date;
  if (str_date.contains(" "))
   str_date = str_date.substring(0, str_date.indexOf(" "));
  formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
  date = (Date) formatter.parse(str_date);
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  cal.setTime(date);
  return cal;
 }

Comment: Now I call My Function In This Way    :                              
   Date date=new Date();
  String strDate=convertDateToString(date);
  Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
  cal=getCalendarFromString(strDate);
  activityData.setDueDate(cal);

Comment: ERROR:  Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2014/04/16"
 at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
 at com.clopay.WebService.MethodsForInsertionOfTask.getCalendarFromString(MethodsForInsertionOfTask.java:102)
 at com.clopay.WebService.MethodsForInsertionOfTask.insertActivityPreprocessing(MethodsForInsertionOfTask.java:51)
 at com.clopay.WebService.MethodsForInsertionOfTask.main(MethodsForInsertionOfTask.java:163)

Answer (score 0):

Below program is what i got from the code you provided. There is no problem with the code.

I assume you are getting error in **setDueDate()** function, but you did not provide it

```
    public class ConvertDateToCalender
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Date date = new Date();
                String strDate = convertDateToString(date);

                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal = getCalendarFromString(strDate);

                //activityData.setDueDate(cal);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }   
        }

        private static String convertDateToString(Date date)
        {
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd"); 
            date=new Date(); 
            String strDate=dateFormat.format(date);
            return strDate; 
        } 

        private static Calendar getCalendarFromString(String str_date) throws ParseException 
        { 
            DateFormat formatter;
            Date date; 

            if (str_date.contains(" ")) 
                str_date = str_date.substring(0, str_date.indexOf(" "));

            formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd"); 
            date = (Date) formatter.parse(str_date);

            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
            cal.setTime(date); 
            return cal; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: setDueDate() function is an inbuilt function that is provided by oracle which accepts only calendar type argument.But I should send the Date value in the form of Calendar which is not being possible since 2 days...this is the issue I am facing

Comment: @Snidgha why is there an if condition to check for space (" ") in getCalendarFromString() function. Are you sure the str_date passed is in the format "yyyy/MM/dd".

Comment: Actually that code is not required.ye str_date is the required format.but,when I parse it to date again the format is being changed

Comment: @Snidgha I don't see any problem running the code from my side. My last guess would be to set Locale of SimpleDateFormat. Get your locale as Locale.getDefault()

Comment: Hey kaleel..issue got solved.AS I am writing client for webservice,I checked the type of the field that I want to populate in webservice.It was given as xsd:Date. I checked the timezone of xsd:date format passed the calendar object with the xsd:Date timezone.It worked...:)