# Make operation on a date in Java

Tags: java, date

What is the best way to make operation on a `util.date`  Object in java.

For example:
I have a date  2018.10.02 and i want to add 3 Month to this date and to get another `util.date` object with the good date.

The same with adding or substracting day, years or hours...

Thanks

Comment: the best way is to use the new Date types

Comment: using Calendar class. look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6186006/3627279)

Comment: I saw this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/23438360/3767862 but i want to get a Date object and not a LocalDate

Comment: Always search Stack Overflow before posting. Specifically: Search for [`LocalDate` class with its *plus*](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+java+LocalDate+plus&t=osx&ia=web) & *minus* methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `java.time` package since java8, for example:

```
Date date = new Date();

Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(date.getTime());

ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.systemDefault());
zonedDateTime = zonedDateTime.plusMonths(3);

Date afterThreeMonth = Date.from(zonedDateTime.toInstant())
```

Comment: And how can i get back a Date?

Comment: @shmoolki See the updated answer.

Comment: If using Java 8 or later and indispensably needing an old-fashioned `Date` object for an API that you don’t want to upgrade just now, the following is slightly simpler: `Date.from(zonedDateTime.toInstant())`.

Comment: @OleV.V. thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

New class `java.time.LocalDate` is better for that kind of operations:

```
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("2018-10-02").plusMonths(3);
```

Comment: I need a Util.date on result