# Getting current datetime using Calendar.getInstance() vs new GregorianCalendar()

Tags: java, calendar, gregorian-calendar

What might be the difference between getting datetime using

`Calendar.getInstance()`

vs

`new GregorianCalendar()`

?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Looking in the source of [Calendar.getInstance()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getInstance%28%29):

```
private static Calendar createCalendar(TimeZone zone, Locale aLocale) {
    // If the specified locale is a Thai locale, returns a BuddhistCalendar
    // instance.
    if ("th".equals(aLocale.getLanguage())
        && ("TH".equals(aLocale.getCountry()))) {
        return new sun.util.BuddhistCalendar(zone, aLocale);
    } else if ("JP".equals(aLocale.getVariant())
        && "JP".equals(aLocale.getCountry())
        && "ja".equals(aLocale.getLanguage())) {
        return new JapaneseImperialCalendar(zone, aLocale);
    }       

    // else create the default calendar
    return new GregorianCalendar(zone, aLocale);    
}
```

So `getInstance()` will return a `Calendar` based on your default `Locale` and `TimeZone`.

Comment: It is worth noting that Android's implementation is different than this, at least in API-22 - `public static synchronized Calendar getInstance() {
        return new GregorianCalendar();
    }`

Answer (score 34):

[`Calendar.getInstance()`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Calendar.java.html) will give you a `Calendar` using the **default time zone and locale**, which can result in a `GregorianCalendar`, a `BuddhistCalendar`, or a `JapaneseImperialCalendar`.

`GregorianCalendar` will always give you, well, a Gregorian calendar.