# How i can convert a date object into a calender object

Tags: java, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Date object to Calendar [Java]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727698/date-object-to-calendar-java)

I have a Java Date object like

```
     Date A = Mon Nov 07 00:00:00 CET 2011;
```

I want to get the year ,month and day. But i saw like these getYear ,getMonth and getDay is deprecated. So how can i extract the above from the above date object.

Comment: Try searching for identical questions before posting! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727698/date-object-to-calendar-java

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Calendar.setTime()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setTime%28java.util.Date%29).

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
Date a = new Date();
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(a);
```

Answer (score 2):

try something like this:

```
    Date d = new Date();
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(d);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
c.setTime(new Date());
int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```