# Two TimePickers comparison

Tags: android, alarmmanager, datetimepicker, android-jobscheduler

So I have allowed the user to pick two Dates Start and End time and connected to Notification Method that will check if the Current time is between his choosing. However the comparison doesn't seem to return the correct result. 
Here are the method inside the `BrodcatRecevier`:

```
    public void CheackAlarmAllow(){
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    FinalTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    FinalTime.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    FinalTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    FinalTime.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    FinalTimeS = dateFormat.format (FinalTime.getTime());


    DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    ProfileHelper response = db.getNotification();

    try {
        FirstTime = dateFormat.parse (response.StartTimePicker);
        SecondTime = dateFormat.parse (response.EndimePicker);
        FinalTimeD = dateFormat.parse (FinalTimeS);


    }catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    if(FinalTimeD.after(FirstTime)&& FinalTime.before(SecondTime))
    {
        Log.w("Not Allowed","Working");
    }
    else
    {
        Log.w("FirstTime", String.valueOf(FirstTime));
        Log.w("Second", String.valueOf(SecondTime));
        Log.w("Final", String.valueOf(FinalTimeD));
        Log.w(" Allowed","Working");
        createNotification();
    }
}
```

And Here the Log returns.

```
06-03 08:14:10.597 30078-7708/com.ahmad.Project W/FirstTime: Thu Jan 01 
03:00:00 MST 1970

06-03 08:14:10.598 30078-7708/com.ahmad. Project W/Second: Thu Jan 01 
10:00:00 MST 1970

06-03 08:14:10.598 30078-7708/com.ahmad. Project W/Final: Thu Jan 01 
08:14:00 MST 1970

06-03 08:14:10.598 30078-7708/com.ahmad. Project W/ Allowed: Working
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if check `if(FinalTimeD.after(FirstTime)&& FinalTime.before(SecondTime))`  fails because `FirstTime` and `SeconfTime` are of type `Date` and `Calendar.after()` returns `true` only if the param passed is of type `Calendar`
From the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) of `Calender.after()`:-

> public boolean after(Object when) Returns whether this Calendar
>   represents a time after the time represented by the specified Object.
>   This method is equivalent to:
>   compareTo(when) > 0   if and only if when is a Calendar instance. Otherwise, the method returns false.

**EDIT** (Copying code snippet from comments below for completeness)

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); 
Date newDate = calendar.setTime(date);
```

Comment: ok Cool, then i have to convert them into Calender's again. How can i do that

Comment: Take look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727698/date-object-to-calendar-java and https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-convert-date-to-calendar-example/

Comment: `Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();`  
`Date newDate = calendar.setTime(date);`

Comment: So i add this line        Calendar CFirstTime =  Calendar.getInstance();
        CFirstTime.setTime (FirstTime); However it gave an error saying Error:(90, 30) error: incompatible types: Calendar cannot be converted to Date

Comment: Perfect, i just initialized it at the top and it Worked. Thank you Zakir